# EnterpriseConnection works, MetadataConnection doesn't

Tags: metadata-api

I have a method

```
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.*;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.*;
....
    public static EnterpriseConnection connectToSalesforce()
    throws ConnectionException
    {
        EnterpriseConnection connection = null;

        String username      = "myname";
        String password      = "mysecret";
        String securityToken = "bigstring";
        String authEndPoint = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/24.0/";
        ConnectorConfig connConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
        connConfig.setUsername(username);
        connConfig.setPassword(password + securityToken);
        connConfig.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
        connection = new EnterpriseConnection(connConfig);

        return connection;
    }
```

that works great. Now I need to experiment with Metadata API so I copied the above with a few tweaks

```
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.*;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.*;
import com.sforce.soap.metadata.*;
....
    public static MetadataConnection connectToSalesforceMetadata()
    throws ConnectionException
    {
        MetadataConnection connection = null;

        String username      = "myname";
        String password      = "mysecret";
        String securityToken = "bigstring";
        String authEndPoint = "https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/24.0/";
        ConnectorConfig connConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
        connConfig.setUsername(username);
        connConfig.setPassword(password + securityToken);
        connConfig.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
        connection = new MetadataConnection(connConfig);

        return connection;
    }
```

But connectToSalesforceMetadata() fails with a MalformedURLException. What's up with that?

Follow-on question: the Metadata API makes reference to a createMetadata() method that returns a SaveResult[] . But I don't have visibility to that method from neither an instance of EnterpriseConnection nor MetadataConnection . Am I missing an import ?

TIA,

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick. I use my already-working method to create an EnterpriseConnection then use that to create the MetadataConnection. Works like a charm.

```
    public static MetadataConnection connectToSalesforceMetadata()
    throws ConnectionException
    {
        MetadataConnection mconnection = null;

        EnterpriseConnection econnection = connectToSalesforce();
        LoginResult lr = econnection.login( econnection.getConfig().getUsername(), econnection.getConfig().getPassword());

        ConnectorConfig connConfig = new ConnectorConfig();
        connConfig.setSessionId( lr.getSessionId());
        connConfig.setServiceEndpoint( lr.getMetadataServerUrl());
        mconnection = new MetadataConnection( connConfig);

        return mconnection;
    }
```

Thanks to all to replied!

CASE CLOSED

Still-learning Steve

Comment: You can accept your answer now - you don't get any reputation points, but it's helpful for others!

Answer (score 1):

On follow up question: "CreateMetadata" resource is available from API v30 onwards. As v30 is not GA yet, you need to connect to a prerelease spring14 org to avail this resource.

Comment: Ah, a versioning issue. Good catch! I'll stick with AsyncResult[] xxx = metadataConnection.create()  then.